# Passing the output of locate as an argument to an editor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pipe

What I mean is doing this in a 1-liner:

```
ubu@ubuntu:~$ locate filename.sh
/home/ubu/path/to/filename.sh
ubu@ubuntu:~$ gedit /home/ubu/path/to/filename.sh
```

I can't seem to figure out the right piping to do so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Simple but limited solutions

If there is only file named `filename.sh` on your system, this will likely work

```
gedit "$(locate filename.sh)"
```

Or, as Hennes points out, if the file name is in your PATH:

```
gedit "$(which filename.sh)"
```

There is another problem with both of these: the shell strips trailing newlines from command substitution, `$(...)`.  So, in the pathological case that your file name ends with newlines, this will fail.

#### General solution

To avoid those issues, try:

```
locate -0 "filename.sh" | xargs --null gedit
```

This will open a tab in `gedit` for each file found.

The `-0` option tells `locate` to return a null-separated list of file names.  The `--null` option tells `xargs` to interpret its input as a null-separated list.  Consequently, this will work with file names with newlines or other difficult characters.

For convenience, you can create the shell function:

```
lge() { locate -0 "$@" | xargs --null gedit; }
```

And use it as: `lge filename.sh`

To make the function definition permanent, place it in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Ah, that did it. I was looking for something like `locate filename | gedit`

Comment: +1 for "the pathological case that your file name ends with newlines"

Comment: If filename.sh is in your path your could use which. 
Example: gedit \`which filename.sh\`

Comment: @Hennes  Good point.  Answer updated.

Comment: And updated with the proper syntax $( ). I still tend to use backticks, but $() is better.